# License Enforcement for SharePoint 2016

Tags: license

Please advice on License Enforcement for SharePoint 2016? I am unable to find any info over the same. Is this same as Sharepoint 2013 using Poweshell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is identical to SharePoint 2013. You can use the same PowerShell methods.

Comment: Thanks . Wanted to check if there has been some enhancement made by Microsoft on same?

Comment: No, there have been no changes in the licensing enforcement. Follow the SharePoint 2013 documentation for the complete details.

Comment: Thanks for the info , you can have a look more info on the SharePoint licensing details at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZF-b-U5LaY&t=1s